# Vectors in a span

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

> Is $u$ in the span of $v$ and $w$ or not? 
>    $$
> u = \begin{pmatrix}-4\\ -18\\ -17\end{pmatrix},\quad
> v = \begin{pmatrix}-4\\ -7\\ -5\end{pmatrix},\quad
> w = \begin{pmatrix}5\\ -3\\ 2\end{pmatrix}
> $$

---

So I am not entirely sure how I would figure this out. Do I have to do row reduction and see what results I get. But that does not seem to be possible because this is a single column vector.

Any help?

Comment: Do you understand what "u in the span of v and w" means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the system$$x\begin{pmatrix}-4\\-7\\-5\end{pmatrix}+y\begin{pmatrix}5\\-3\\2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-4\\-18\\-7,\end{pmatrix}$$that is,$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}-4x+5y=-4\\-7x-3y=-18\\-5x+2y=-7.\end{array}\right.$$Either it has solutions, or it hasn't. In the first case, $u$ belongs to the space spanned by $v$ and $w$; otherwise, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You surely can do row reduction on the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-4 & 5 & -4 \\
-7 & -3 & -18 \\
-5 & 2 & -17
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This amounts to
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
-4 & 5 & -4 \\
-7 & -3 & -18 \\
-5 & 2 & -17
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -5/4 & 1 \\
-7 & -3 & -18 \\
-5 & 2 & -17
\end{bmatrix}
&& R_1\gets -\tfrac{1}{4}R_1
\\[6px]&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -5/4 & 1 \\
0 & -47/4 & -11 \\
0 & -17/4 & -12
\end{bmatrix}
&&\begin{aligned} R_2&\gets R_2+7R_1 \\ R_3&\gets R_3+5R_1\end{aligned}
\end{align}
and now it's apparent that the matrix has rank $3$ (you can end the reduction).